# Aftter conversion to .NET 6.0, question mark is added to text

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf, upgrade, .net-6.0

We have an ASP.NET Web API project that gets data from Java service that lives in Web Sphere and is exposed as a WCF service. After conversion to .NET 6.0, the Sax parser on the server side fails due to a `?` added to the beginning of the text.

We are sending

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="REQUEST">
    ...
</Message>
```

With .NET 4.8 and .NET 5.0, we do not have any problem.

With .NET 6, on the server side, a `?` shows up:

```
?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

On the client, in the debugger or when I save the serialized string to a file the extra `?` is not present.

The entire string is created via deserialization of an instance of C# class and after calling `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`

The only change is the upgrade to .NET 6.

Any suggestion is appreciated, thank you.

**Update more details**
the message is contracted from an instance of c# class that has properties that some of them are classes too example you can see below

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Message")]
public class RequestMessage
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Content")]
    public RequestContent Content { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Serialization is done by:

```
public static string Serialize(object obj)
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ser.Serialize(outStream, obj);
        outStream.Flush();
        byte[] buffer = outStream.GetBuffer();
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, 
                                  (int)outStream.Position);
    }
}
```

Sending request via creating WCF channel and executing service method:

```
{
SecureMessageHandlerServiceChannel channelClient =
        _wcfSecureMessageHandlerServicefactory.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(AuthenticatedHandlerServiceURL));
    OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(channelClient);
    ServiceRequestBody requestBody =
        new ServiceRequestBody(secureMessageSerializationType.XML_DIFF_GRAM, serializedInput);
    var serviceRequest = new ServiceRequest(requestBody);
    ServiceResponse resp = channelClient.Service(req);
}
```

We consume WCF services via service references that were created manually, see picture below for list of files
[image: list of files]

Again none of it has changed only upgrade to .NET6.0

Comment: Somewhere you lost utf-8 encoding. If you provide more details how do you prepare the payload and call the server, it might help to identify the problem.

Comment: Almost feels like a Byte Order Mark is being pre-pended to the data somehow. Can you dump the hex for the data that is being sent over the wire?

Comment: @SergeyL, I provided more details

Comment: First, why does `Serialize` exist in the first place? WCF doesn't use a SAX parser, XmlSerializer is a DOM parser and shouldn't be used directly by application code. Using XmlSerializer attributes in WCF is uncommon, which suggests the classes themselves were generated by a tool

Comment: `only upgrade to .NET6.0` that's not "only. .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6 and WCF was never officially ported to .NET Core. [CoreWCF](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upgrading-a-wcf-service-to-dotnet-6/) is a community project to port WCF to .NET Core that released its first stable version just this month. The [project's repo](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF/) has a [Walkthrough](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF/blob/main/Documentation/Walkthrough.md) that shows which packages to install and how to use them to create a WCF service

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, based on MS Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-6.0 "Serializes and deserializes objects into and from XML documents. The XmlSerializer enables you to control how objects are encoded into XML. " - that's what we needed, do not see any issues, please elaborate

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos regarding only upgrade - the same code works fine with net4.8. no issues at all.  regarding WCF in .net core; here is an article:https://www.thecodebuzz.com/consuming-wcf-web-services-in-net-core-best-practices/  describing how to consume WCF services from .NET Core application, so there is no issue to consume and we have been doing it for over a year. again the issue arose after converting to .NET6.0

Comment: No you didn't need it, because WCF takes care of serialization itself using the "new" (in 2008) DataContractSerializer class. You don't even see this, this is handled by the runtime. That serializer is stricter than XmlSerializer and enforces web service interoperability rules. The only reason the *legacy* XmlSerializer class was used since 2008 was when the data objects broke the interop rules. Quite often, that was the case when WCF was used to call an ancient ASMX service. The CoreWCF walkthrough shows what a WCF project should look like - no Xml attributes, no calls to Serialize

Comment: `regarding only upgrade` I repeat. You moved from .NET Framework to .NET Core. That's a **completely different runtime**. It **doesn't include WCF at all**. You can't expect your old code to work at all. You can't even read `web.config`, it's no longer used. You need to add a compatibility NuGet package to read `app.config` and `web.config` settings

Comment: @omajid, I added Hex dump

Answer (score 0):

For posterity:
After bootstrapping to bare bones the issue turns out to be

```
public static string Serialize(object obj)
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ser.Serialize(outStream, obj);
        outStream.Flush();
        byte[] buffer = outStream.GetBuffer();
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, 
                                  (int)outStream.Position);
    }
}
```

I changed it to

```
public static string Serialize(object obj)
{
  XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
  using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
  {
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, IndentChars = "    " };
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
    {
      ser.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
    }
    return textWriter.ToString();
  }
}
```

that solved the issue.